# What would be considered a standard deviation boundry for java random?

Tags: java, random, ab-testing

I'm using java 6 random (java.util.Random,linux 64) to randomly decide between serving one version of a page to a second one (Normal A/B testing), technically i initialize the class once with the default empty constructor and it's injected to a bean (Spring) as a property . 
Most of the times the copies of the pages are within 8%(+-) of each other but from time to time i see deviations of up to 20 percent , e.g :

I now have two copies that split : 680 / 570 is that considered normal ? 
Is there a better/faster version to use than java random ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deviation of 20% does seem rather large, but you would need to talk to a trained statistician to find out if it is statistically anomalous.

**UPDATE** - and the answer is that it is not necessarily anomalous.  The statistics predict that you would get an outlier like this roughly 0.3% of the time.

---

It is certainly plausible for a result like this to be caused by the random number generator.  The `Random` class uses a simple "linear congruential" algorithm, and this class of algorithms are strongly auto-correlated.  Depending on how you use the random number, this could lead anomalies at the application level.

If this is the cause of your problem, then you could try replacing it with a crypto-strength random number generator.  See the javadocs for [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).  `SecureRandom` is more expensive than `Random`, but it is unlikely that this will make any difference in your use-case.

---

On the other hand, if these outliers are actually happening at roughly the rate predicted by the theory, changing the random number generator shouldn't make any difference.

If these outliers are really troublesome, then you need to take a different approach.  Instead of generating N random choices, generate a list of false / true with exactly the required ratio, and then shuffle the list; e.g. using [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).

Comment: 680 / 570 means a deviation of 55 on a sample of 1250. This is only 3x the standard deviation, so it occurs in 0.3% of the cases. SecureRandom is not less random than Random, so it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is fairly normal as it is meant to generate random sequences. If you want repeated patterns after certain interval, I think you may want to use a specific `seed` value in the constructor and reset the random with same seed after certain interval.

e.g. after every 100/500/n calls to `Random.next..`, reset the seed with old value using `Random.setSeed(long seed)` method.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Random.nextBoolean() is an approach for a standard binomial distribution, which has standard deviation of sqrt(n*p*(1-p)), with p=0.5.

So if you do 900 iterations, the standard deviation is sqrt(900*.5*.5) = 15, so most times the distribution would be in the range 435 - 465.

However, it is pseudo-random, and has a limited cycle of numbers it will go through before starting over. So if you have enough iterations, the actual deviation will be much smaller than the theoretical one. Java uses the formula seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1). You could write a different formula with smaller numbers to purposely obtain a smaller deviation, which would make it a worse random number generator, but better fitted for your purpose.

You could for example create a list of 5 trues and 5 falses in it, and use Collections.shuffle to randomize the list. Then you iterate over them sequentially. After 10 iterations you re-shuffle the list and start from the beginning. That way you'll never deviate more than 5.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator for the mathematics.